# Oracle query to find previous 2 entries

Tags: oracle10g

```
EMP     Code      Date
123     'ESL'     '10-12-2020'
123     'ASU'     '10-09-2020'
123     'PTO'     '10-07-2020'


EMP     Code      Date
567     'ESL'     '10-12-2020'
567     'PTO'     '10-09-2020'
567     'PTO'     '10-07-2020'
```

From the above data sample I need a query that will pull all the ESL records where the previous 2 entries aren't PTO so in my 2 examples only the first example should be "flagged" and be returned by the query. I tried the following to no avail

```
select * from timedetail t where t.empnum = '000270172' and t.ppenddate = '22-aug-2020' and t.doecode = 'ESL'
and not exists(select 'x' from timedetail t2 where t2.empnum = '000270172' = t.empnum and t2.tsdate < t.tsdate and t2.doecode = PTO')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `COUNT` analytic function with a window of the 2 preceding rows:

```sql
SELECT emp,
       code,
       "DATE"
FROM (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( CASE code WHEN 'PTO' THEN 1 END ) OVER (
             PARTITION BY emp ORDER BY "DATE"
             ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
           ) num_pto
  FROM   timedetail t
)
WHERE code = 'ESL'
AND   num_pto < 2;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE timedetail ( emp, code, "DATE" ) AS
  SELECT 123, 'ESL', DATE '2020-10-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'ASU', DATE '2020-10-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, 'PTO', DATE '2020-10-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 567, 'ESL', DATE '2020-10-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 567, 'PTO', DATE '2020-10-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 567, 'PTO', DATE '2020-10-07' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> EMP | CODE | DATE     
> --: | :--- | :--------
> 123 | ESL  | 12-OCT-20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b7d9227a477b24ba2648e8f26f81aecf)*